# Create Animation for Image WinPhone

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation

How to create animation for Image in WinPhone?
I created UniformGrid, which has 20 images. How do the following: when pressed on the image - to play animation?

**My ItemControl:**

```
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image x:Name="imgSquare"
                           Source="{Binding Path=Square.ImagePath, Converter={StaticResource PathWP}}"                          
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Width="110" 
                           Height="110" 
                           Stretch="Fill">

                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                <commandbinding:MvxEventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ClickCommand, ElementName=ImageList}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>                            
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <behaviors:ImageBehavior SelectedSquareModel="{Binding}"/>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                    </Image>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

**I plan to play the animation using the Behavior:**

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
     <behaviors:ImageBehavior SelectedSquareModel="{Binding}"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

**Tell me please how to create an animation, and connect it to the Image?**

*Excuse me for my bad English*

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for '[animations in windows phone](http://www.bing.com/search?q=animations%20in%20windows%20phone&form=MOZSBR&pc=MOZI)'

You will find lots of great tutorials, most of them using Blend and Behaviors like: http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/29/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-29-animations/

For button pressing animations done in code see the middle few minutes of http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5k8SG82e1Rc - although the source was in ruby!